# How to convert a string of strings into a list?

Tags: python, string, list

I have the string

"Abarth", "AC", "Aixam", "Ak", "Alfa%20Romeo", "Alpine", "Ariel", "Aston%20Martin", "Audi", "Austin", "Bac", "Beauford", "Bentley", "BMW", "Bristol", "Bugatti", "Buick", "Cadillac", "Caterham", "Chesil", "Chevrolet", "Chrysler", "Citroen", "Corvette", "Cupra", "Custom%20Vehicle", "Dacia", "Daewoo", "Daihatsu", "Daimler", "Datsun", "DAX", "Dodge", "DS%20AUTOMOBILES", "Ferrari", "Fiat", "Ford", "GMC", "Great%20Wall", "Holden", "Honda", "Humber", "Hummer", "Hyundai", "Infiniti", "Isuzu", "Iveco", "Jaguar", "Jeep", "Jensen", "Kia", "Koenigsegg", "KTM", "Lamborghini", "Lancia", "Land%20Rover", "Levc", "Lexus", "Leyland", "Lincoln", "Lotus", "Maserati", "Maybach", "Mazda", "McLaren", "Mercedes-Benz", "MG", "MINI", "Mitsubishi", "Morgan", "Morris", "Nissan", "Noble", "Opel", "Perodua", "Peugeot", "Pilgrim", "Plymouth", "Pontiac", "Porsche", "Proton", "Radical", "Raw", "Reliant", "Renault", "Replica", "Riley", "Robin%20Hood", "Rolls-Royce", "Rover", "Saab", "SEAT", "SKODA", "Smart", "Ssangyong", "Standard", "Subaru", "Sunbeam", "Suzuki", "Tesla", "Tiger", "Toyota", "Triumph", "TVR", "Vauxhall", "Volkswagen", "Volvo", "Westfield", "Yamaha", "Zenos"

which is stored by the variable "list_of_car_makes" in my python project

but I want to convert the string into a list, how would I do that?
when I use print(list_of_car_makes[0]) it prints the first character in the string, the ",
what i'd like to be able to print is Abarth when using that print function.

Comment: How are you creating this string in the first place?

Comment: This is definetly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). From where are you getting this string? There must be a way to avoid that massive blunder

Answer (score 1):

Okay you have other weird characters in there what I'm going to ignore (%20 is a space, but you can work out how to fix that)

Your issue to the letter would be solved by:

```py
your_string_here.replace('"', '').split(',')
```

Comment: Also consider if there are double quotes within the strings. You lose them this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
makes = []
word = ""
for c in list_of_car_makes:
    if c in " ,":
        continue

    if c == '"':
        if word:
            makes.append(word)
            word = ""
        continue

    word += c

print(makes)
```

Output:

```
['Abarth', 'AC', 'Aixam', 'Ak', 'Alfa%20Romeo', 'Alpine', 'Ariel', 'Aston%20Martin', 'Audi', 'Austin', 'Bac', 'Beauford', 'Bentley', 'BMW', 'Bristol', 'Bugatti', 'Buick', 'Cadillac', 'Caterham', 'Chesil', 'Chevrolet', 'Chrysler', 'Citroen', 'Corvette', 'Cupra', 'Custom%20Vehicle', 'Dacia', 'Daewoo', 'Daihatsu', 'Daimler', 'Datsun', 'DAX', 'Dodge', 'DS%20AUTOMOBILES', 'Ferrari', 'Fiat', 'Ford', 'GMC', 'Great%20Wall', 'Holden', 'Honda', 'Humber', 'Hummer', 'Hyundai', 'Infiniti', 'Isuzu', 'Iveco', 'Jaguar', 'Jeep', 'Jensen', 'Kia', 'Koenigsegg', 'KTM', 'Lamborghini', 'Lancia', 'Land%20Rover', 'Levc', 'Lexus', 'Leyland', 'Lincoln', 'Lotus', 'Maserati', 'Maybach', 'Mazda', 'McLaren', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'MG', 'MINI', 'Mitsubishi', 'Morgan', 'Morris', 'Nissan', 'Noble', 'Opel', 'Perodua', 'Peugeot', 'Pilgrim', 'Plymouth', 'Pontiac', 'Porsche', 'Proton', 'Radical', 'Raw', 'Reliant', 'Renault', 'Replica', 'Riley', 'Robin%20Hood', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Rover', 'Saab', 'SEAT', 'SKODA', 'Smart', 'Ssangyong', 'Standard', 'Subaru', 'Sunbeam', 'Suzuki', 'Tesla', 'Tiger', 'Toyota', 'Triumph', 'TVR', 'Vauxhall', 'Volkswagen', 'Volvo', 'Westfield', 'Yamaha', 'Zenos']
```

---

To remove the `%20` (and other codes, add this bit of code):

```
for j in range(len(makes)):
    while "%" in makes[j]:
        i = makes[j].find("%")
        s = int(makes[j][i+1:i+3], base=16)
        m = list(makes[j])
        del m[i:i+3]
        m.insert(i, chr(s))
        makes[j] = ''.join(m)
```

Output with this code:

```
['Abarth', 'AC', 'Aixam', 'Ak', 'Alfa Romeo', 'Alpine', 'Ariel', 'Aston Martin', 'Audi', 'Austin', 'Bac', 'Beauford', 'Bentley', 'BMW', 'Bristol', 'Bugatti', 'Buick', 'Cadillac', 'Caterham', 'Chesil', 'Chevrolet', 'Chrysler', 'Citroen', 'Corvette', 'Cupra', 'Custom Vehicle', 'Dacia', 'Daewoo', 'Daihatsu', 'Daimler', 'Datsun', 'DAX', 'Dodge', 'DS AUTOMOBILES', 'Ferrari', 'Fiat', 'Ford', 'GMC', 'Great Wall', 'Holden', 'Honda', 'Humber', 'Hummer', 'Hyundai', 'Infiniti', 'Isuzu', 'Iveco', 'Jaguar', 'Jeep', 'Jensen', 'Kia', 'Koenigsegg', 'KTM', 'Lamborghini', 'Lancia', 'Land Rover', 'Levc', 'Lexus', 'Leyland', 'Lincoln', 'Lotus', 'Maserati', 'Maybach', 'Mazda', 'McLaren', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'MG', 'MINI', 'Mitsubishi', 'Morgan', 'Morris', 'Nissan', 'Noble', 'Opel', 'Perodua', 'Peugeot', 'Pilgrim', 'Plymouth', 'Pontiac', 'Porsche', 'Proton', 'Radical', 'Raw', 'Reliant', 'Renault', 'Replica', 'Riley', 'Robin Hood', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Rover', 'Saab', 'SEAT', 'SKODA', 'Smart', 'Ssangyong', 'Standard', 'Subaru', 'Sunbeam', 'Suzuki', 'Tesla', 'Tiger', 'Toyota', 'Triumph', 'TVR', 'Vauxhall', 'Volkswagen', 'Volvo', 'Westfield', 'Yamaha', 'Zenos']
```

Comment: You legend, that works perfect! Thank you very much. As an fyi, I need the %20 in there and had to do some .replace trickery to get them there in the first place.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest splitting by your delimiter then using `str.split` as you can provide it with characters to trim from the ends of a string.

```
[s.strip('"') for s in your_string.split(', ')]
```

You can even replace `%20` with a space this way.

```
[s.strip('"').replace('%20', ' ') for s in your_string.split(', ')]
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/FunnyLikableLanservers)